# Your developer license has expired (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8

My temporary developer license (using Visual Studio 2011 Beta and Windows 8 Consumer Preview) expired and a popup asked me to aply for a new one. This all seemed to work, but when I build and deploy to the local machine it takes me to the app store and tells me that the developer license has expired.

I've tried:

- Unistalling my app from the home screen
- Cleaning my project solution
- Removing my developer license using powershell command Unregister-WindowsDeveloperLicense and getting new license again
- Restarting machine

I can create new projects that build and deploy fine, but my existing project is stuffed. Is the old licence cached somewhere and how can I get it to forget about it.

There is this [similar quesion on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh696646%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Someone managed to solve it, but there solution has not worked for me and there are other people saying it hasn't worked for them.

Comment: If you run the Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration command do you see the expired license or your new one?

Comment: It kicks off a dialogue box that says it's renewing my developer licence and then returns with one that expires on 14 June. The same happens if I do it again. So it looks like it might be failing to save it.

Comment: I understand this is a common problem. I would expect Microsoft to have a reliable fix before long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first month this happened to me, a reboot solved it. The second time it didn't. I went into my package manifest and changed the package ID. It looked like a GUID and I just put kmg on the end. Then everything worked fine. Later I tried changing it back but it failed again so I guess my package ID ends in kmg now :-)

I believe it's because you're trying to overwrite a package that was shipped by a "different developer". They're going to have to fix that somehow but hey, this is what betas ^H^H^H^H^H previews are for, right?

Comment: I changed the last digit and it sorted me out. Thanks loads Kate. I can stop banging my head against hard objects now.